# nginx giving 500 for images and for some api's

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, images, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have a site deployed on crafter, when we access it directly with "IP:port" it works fine.
But when we are accessing it with Nginx reverse proxy, it gives 500 for images and other api's.

Also it is not giving any error in nginx error.log

Request you to please help, we are stuck here.

Comment: Increase log verbosity. The only way to solve 500 errors is the error log.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a multitude of reasons as to why you are seeing 500 code errors

As suggested in the comment, you need to increase the log verbosity to get more details about the error

Based on your nginx configuration, the error file can be `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or a different one.
Alternatively you can check the logs using `journalctl` depending on the service management system in place

It could potentially be a `permission denied` issue when accessing the static files so you need to make sure the user spawning the nginx processes has the correct access level

Please share the nginx configuration file and the permissions associated to the files to be served

Comment: Crafter site required cookies to set, nginx rewrite rule solved my problem. @Tewfik thanks for your input